# React.js - Render Components with Different Styles based on props

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactive-programming

So let's say I am creating a simple web layout, where I have a feedback message component above the `MainContent` component, as so:

```
class WebLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <Header />
      <FeedBackMessage 
        shouldRenderMessage={true}
        typeMessage={"error"}
        message={"Wrong input!"}
      />
      <MainContent />
    </div>
  }
}
```

And let's assume that I have different types of messages such as `error`, `warning`, `success`.

Inside the `FeedBackMessage`, I may have something as so:

```
class FeedBackMessage extends Component {
  renderMessage(){
    const {shouldRenderMessage, typeMessage, message } = this.props;
    if (shouldRenderMessage === true){
      <div>
        {message}
      </div>
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderMessage().bind(this)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am stumped on how I can render `FeedBackMessage` styling based on `typeMessage` prop value.

For instance, if I pass `typeMessage` with 'error', I like to have the `FeedbackMessage` component with a red border styling. Or if I pass `confirm`, I'd like to render with green border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all is very dependent on your styling solution.

**If you want to use inline styles** it might look something like this:

```
class FeedBackMessage extends Component {
  renderMessage(){
    const {shouldRenderMessage, typeMessage, message } = this.props;
    if (shouldRenderMessage === true){
      <div>
        {message}
      </div>
    }
  }
  render(){
    const componentStyle = {
      error: { border: "1px solid red" },
      confirm: { border: "1px solid green" }
    }[this.props.typeMessage];

    return (
      <div style={componentStyle}>
        {this.renderMessage().bind(this)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**If you want to style with stylesheets**, you can use something like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) to toggle classes based on some logic and then add the class your component.

```
class FeedBackMessage extends Component {
  renderMessage(){
    const {shouldRenderMessage, typeMessage, message } = this.props;
    if (shouldRenderMessage === true){
      <div>
        {message}
      </div>
    }
  }
  render(){
    const componentClass = classNames('FeedBackMessage', {
      "error": this.props.typeName === 'error',
      "confirm": this.props.typeName === 'confirm'
    });

    return (
      <div className={componentClass}>
        {this.renderMessage().bind(this)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And have a stylesheet like so:

```
.FeedBackMessage .error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.FeedbackMessage .confirm {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! 
Is there any way to use DRY practices? For instance, what would happen if I have 10+ different messages? With your method, it would mean that I would have to have 10+ different css classNames

Comment: In terms of DRY, you aren't really repeating yourself if you need different behavior based on the typeName. If there are like 3 different possible colors, you might be able to re-use the same classnames and just have a 1 to many mapping between classnames and typeNames.

You can probably make it more terse by using `this.props.typeName` as the className - but you'd still have 10+ classes.

If you really think this is all still too many classes, you might want to try inline styles to avoid classes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation will help you. Please check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

```
render() {
  let className = 'menu';
  if (this.props.isActive) {
    className += ' menu-active';
  }

  return <span className={className}>Menu</span>
}
```